# undefine javascript file default/js/skinLoader.js

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I am getting the error "Undefined JavaScript file("default/js/skinLoader.js" when I create an Ipad or Iphone environment in my Mobilefirst project . My version is 6.3. The file is reference in the skinloader.html file. However,The file  does not exist in the template... How do I resolve this error

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is harmless and you can safely ignore it.

You will get this "error" because you not using a Skin for the specific environment, which is ok. You are not required to use a skin if you do not need one.

If you really want to, you can select to add a new, empty, MFP skin to your iPad environment but there's really no need to.